# How to find number of homomorphisms from :

Tags: abstract-algebra

1.$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

2. $Q_8 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$
3. $Q_8  \to S_3$

For 1,  define  $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ 
By $f(x) = mf(1)$  where $m$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$.
If we know the possibility of $o(f(1))$, then we get find number of homomorphisms since $o(f(1))/o(1)$ and we know  $o(1) = \infty$ 
So possibility for $f(1) = \mathbb{Z}$
Therefore number of homomorphisms are infinite .
 Is this is right or not? And I have no idea about 2,3

Comment: What do you mean by $o(f(1))$?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea for (1). Any homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by where you send $1$. And in the case of $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ there are indeed infinitely many choices.

Now, for $Q_8$ any homomorphism is determined by where $1,i,j,k$ map to. It is similar for both (2) and (3) that way. Recall that there is always the trivial homomorphism which sends everything to the identity. Try and go from there.

## Edit

Also remember that the identity must map to the identity.

Answer (score 2):

**For (a)**:

$f:\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\Bbb{Z}=\langle1\rangle$ is a cyclic group, so if we know $f(1)$, then for $k>0$ we can get $f(k)=f(\underbrace{1+1+\dotsb+1}_{k})=kf(1)$. It can be shown failry easily that $f(n)=nf(1)$ for all $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Without any restrictions on the homomorphism, $f(1)$ can take any integer value, hence infinitely many homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}$ to itself.

**Note:** You mentioned order of $f(1)$: $\text{ord}(f(1))$. In $\Bbb{Z}$, except for the identity element everything else is of infinite order, so the quotient you have written would not make much sense.

**For (b):**

$f:Q_8 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$, we need $f(1)=[0]_6$. Also $i$ is an element of order $4$ in $Q_8$, so $\text{ord}(f(i))$ (in $\Bbb{Z}_6$) should divide $4$. The only possibilities are: $[0],[3]$ (because they have orders $1$ and $2$ respectively). Thus either $f(i)=0$ or $f(i)=3$. Since $i^2=-1$, and $f(-1)=f(i^2)=f(i)+f(i)=2f(i)$, so in both scenarios $f(-1)=0$.

Similarly, we can say $f(j)=0$ or $f(j)=3$. But what about $f(k)$? Since $ij=k$, therefore $f(k)=f(ij)=f(i)+f(j)$. So $f(k)$ will be determined by what choices we make for $f(i)$ and $f(j)$. Also $f(-i)=f((-1)(i))=f(-1)+f(i)=f(i)$, so $f(-i)$ is determined by $f(i)$ (same thing will happen for $f(-j)$ and $f(-k)$).

So we have the following situation:
$$f(1)=0, f(-1)=0, f(i)=0 \text{ or } 3, f(j)=0 \text{ or } 3, f(k)=f(i)+f(j).$$ 
In all we have $4$ choices for $f$.

A similar approach will help you with (c) as well.

---

**Another approach (if you know first isomorphism theorem)**

### For (b):

$f(Q_8)$: the Image of $f$ will be a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_6$. So it's order divides $6$. By first isomorphism theorem, $|Q_8|=|\ker(f)|\cdot |f(Q_8)|$. Thus $|f(Q_8)|$ also divides $8$. Consequently $|f(Q_8)|$ divides $\gcd(6,8)=2$. Thus the possible orders of $f(Q_8)$ are $1,2$. Thereby we can say $|\ker(f)|=8,4$ respectively. But $\ker(f) \leq Q_8$.

Case 1): when $|\ker(f)|=8$, then $\ker(f)=Q_8$. In which case $f$ is a trivial homomorphism.

Case 2): when $|\ker(f)|=4$: Since there are exactly three subgroups of order $4$ in $Q_8$ (namely:$\langle i \rangle, \langle j \rangle$ and $\langle k \rangle$). Therefore we get three corresponding homomorphisms from this.

So in all $4$ homomorphisms.